# nvidia-smi reports 0% memory usage,0% utilization and not gpu process running

Tags: drivers, server, nvidia, cuda

I have this Small server that supports 4 NVIDIA tesla k40M but for some reason, even with the latest drivers and Cuda it just doesn't want to work properly. The GPU's seems to be stuck at 33ghz when I had the original driver the system sounded louder for some reason but it doesn't work properly no matter what driver, 0 percent memory utilization, low power usage, stuck at 33ghz, 0% GPU utilization

[image: Image 2]

Comment: You haven't mentioned your OS/release details, but your picture shows what looks like a windows 10 desktop   (picture are not as easy to read, so please provide text and describe your problem specifically).\

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? What Nvidia drivers did you install and how did you install it? What application/program are you trying to run when you are noticing that the GPU utilization is zero? Please add all of this information to your question.